# profane word regex match not working shi+ does not match properly

Tags: java, regex, word-boundary

```
String stre = "da shi+ jia";
profaneWord= "shi+";
boolean flag = isContain(stre, profaneWord);
private static boolean isContain(String source, String subItem) {
    String pattern = subItem;
    String pat = Pattern.quote(pattern);
    System.out.println("pattern quote example  " + pat);
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\b"+pat+"\b");
    System.out.println("pattern quote example  " + p.toString());
    Matcher m = p.matcher(source);
    return m.find();
}
```

> pattern quote example  \Qshi+\E pattern quote example  \Qshi+\E
>   false

Expected : true

I am using java 7 .

Comment: The `+` character is a special character. You need to escape it with a backslash: `\+`

Comment: not able to escape that throws a compile time error @AutomatedChaos - Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are \b \t \n \f \r \" \' \\ )

Comment: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8065538 similar one

Answer (score 0):

Word boundary escape is `\\b` not `\b`.

```
Pattern.compile("\\b"+pat+"\\b");
```

Comment: pattern quote example  \Qshi+\E
pattern quote example  \b\Qshi+\E\b
false              ----> not working